# How do I create an Automator application that gets a file as an argument and runs a python script with this file in macOS Monterey?

Tags: python, macos, shell, automator

How do I create a mac application using automator, that gets a file that I "drop" in it and executes a python script with this file as an argument?

I tried solutions from various questions that suggest creating a "service" in Automator, but I don't see such option in Automator in Monterey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a new *Application* in Automator
2. Select "run shell script" action from the left sidebar and add it by double-clicking on it
3. Change shell to `/bin/bash/`
4. Change *Pass input* to *as arguments* (refer to a screenshot below)

[image: screenshot of a created automation]

5. Add code to "run shell script block", e.g. add the following code to change directory to your python script directory, activate virtual environment and run a script from it with file passed as argument (use `"$1"` to get a file as argument):

```
cd my_project_directory
source .venv/bin/activate
python my_script.py "$1"
```

6. Save your automation as an application
7. You can now drag and drop any file to the application icon of your saved app in finder to pass it to the script and it will execute

EDIT:

If you want to be able to drop several files on your app at once and run a script for each of them in a sequence, you can change the last line to the following code:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    python my_script.py "$f"
done
```

Comment: This answer works fine for me with the default /bin/zsh. Why do you include the step "Change shell to /bin/bash/"?